# Is it possible to loop through the subplots of a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

So I have a figure with 16 subplots, 4 columns and 4 rows. To start, I focused on getting the subplot in position (0,0) to work properly (which I figured out!), before I moved on getting the loop to work properly.

That's where I'm stuck. Here is what the matplotlib portion of my code looks like:

```
new_list = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten , eleven, twelve, 
    thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen]
color = ['blue','red']

for name in new_list:
    for row in range(0,subplot_shape[0]):
        for col in range(0,subplot_shape[1]):
            display.plot('total', 
                        currentname=name,
                        subplot_index=(row,col),
                        linestyle='-',
                        marker='.',
                        label="RG",
                        color=color[0])
            display.plot('new_total', 
                        currentname=name,
                        subplot_index=(row,col),
                        linestyle='-',
                        marker='.',
                        label="RG New",
                        color=color[1])
            display.axes[row][col].set_title(name + ' Total on ' + date)
            display.axes[row][col].legend()
            display.axes[row][col].autoscale(tight=False, axis='y')
            display.axes[row][col].set_xlim(xrng)
```

With the way I have it set up currently, everything gets plotted on every subplot. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I would like each subplot to have the contents of each dataset named in "new_list". (So, subplot(0,0) would have dataset one, subplot(0,1) would have dataset two, and so on.

Comment: What is “display” in this code? It’s not matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

Use the object-oriented API: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4)`.

Then you can loop through the rows/cols like:

```py
for row, axes_row in enumerate(axes):
    for col, ax in enumerate(axes_row): 
        # do your stuff
        ax.plot(...)
```